# Create TFRecord for each image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

Currently, I have a program which creates a TFRecord containing all images, as array strings, from a directory. Instead of all the image array data being contained in one TFRecord, how would I contain each image array data in a single TFRecord file? E.X. I have 30 images which I convert to arrays (numpy) --> I get 30 TFRecord files.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm
import os


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


tfrecords_filename = 'image001.tfrecords'

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_filename)

path_to_images = 'images_animation'
#List of images - method of accessing images
filenum = len([name for name in os.listdir(path_to_images) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path_to_images, name))])
#Collect the real images to later on compare
#to the reconstructed ones
original_images = []

for p in range(1, filenum):
    fname = "images_animation/image%03d.png" % p
    img = np.array(Image.open(fname))

    # Put in the original images into array
    # Just for future check for correctness
    original_images.append((img))

    img_raw = img.tostring()

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(img_raw)}))

    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
```

Comment: create a single reader with different filename for every image